# Remove lines in Freemarker output

Tags: freemarker

I am generating an odt file using Freemarker template.

My code is:

```
${(addressline1)!}
${(addressline2)!}
${(addressline3)!}
```

The problem is that when addresline1 or addressline2 or is empty, it generates an empty line. If all the fields are empty it generates three empty lines.

I have tried the following things:

1. `[#if addressline2??]${(addressline2)!} [/#if]`
2. `[#if addressline2?has_content]${(addressline2)!} [/#if]`
3. compress directive

   ```
   [@compress] 
   ${(addressline1)!}
   ${(addressline2)!}
   ${(addressline3)!} [/@compress]
   ```

but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: See [FREEMARKER-20](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/)

Comment: Did you managed to solve this problem? I am having the same issue. Only I'm using word template and XDocReport to generate pdf file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you edit the template in OpenOffice/LibreOffice or such visual editor? Because then the problem is that although you just see a `${something}` there, FreeMarker sees `<p>${something}</p>`. As it's just a general purpose template text engine, it won't remove the `<p></p>` that remains there when the inserted text was empty. The application that uses it for `ODT` should give a way of purging empty paragraphs.

Comment: I saw the generated content.xml corresponding to that odt file.  It was <text:p text:style-name="P26">${(addressline1)!} </text:p>.  Is there any way to remove this <p> which is getting added.

Comment: As I said, it's out of scope for FreeMarker. The `p` could be only removed after the `${...}` was resolved by FreeMarker, as only then it's known that the `p` is empty. Or, the ODT generator tools should provide other means of removing enclosing elements. (BTW, it's just `${addressline1!}`, no need for the `()`)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it working by doing this:

```
<#if addressline1 !== ''>${addressline1}</#if>
```

Just repeat the process to check for all 3 variables. Alternatively, if they don't exist rather than them just being empty, this code should do the work:

```
<#if addressline1?exists>${addressline1}</#if>
```

You can find further documentation in the Freemarker Manual website: http://freemarker.org/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. This is what I ended up with:

```
<#assign i2 = ""?left_pad(2*4)>
<#assign i3 = ""?left_pad(3*4)>
...
        <#if dep.version??>${i3}<version>${dep.version}</version>${"\n"}</#if><#t>
...
```

Copied from my bug report:

I'd like to be able to have the NEW LINE generated conditionally, with 1 line of template source code.

```
        <#if dep.classifier??><classifier>${dep.classifier}</classifier></#if>
```

This generates the indent spaces and the newline, no matter what.
{{#t}} and {{#rt}} and {{#lt}} apply at compile time, so they don't care about the condition. So they strip even if the content is there, which I don't want.

I could do this:

```
        <#if dep.classifier??>${"            "}<classifier>${dep.classifier}</classifier>${"\n"}</#if><#t>
```

So that's the request. It can also be anything what helps me achieve that.

Until then, I have to do:

```
        <#if dep.classifier??>
        <classifier>${dep.classifier}</classifier>
        </#if>
```

Which I don't like because it makes the templates way longer.

Or

```
        <#if dep.classifier??><classifier>${dep.classifier}</classifier>
        </#if><#if dep.classifier??><classifier>${dep.classifier}</classifier>
        </#if>
        ...
```

Which I don't like because it's messy.

Or

```
         <#if dep.classifier??>${"         "}<classifier>${dep.classifier}</classifier>${"\n"}</#if><#t>
```

Which I don't like because it adds superfluous pieces to the template.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to place starting <#compress> tag in the previous line of the line you need to remove if empty.

```
${keep this line always}<#compress>
${remove this line if empty}</#compress>
${keep this line always}
```

Works with freemarker 2.3.31